# foselasticabundle nested queries

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

Im using FOSElasticaBundle to integrate my symfony3 project with elasticsearch. I have a mapping similar to:

```
company:
    mappings:
        id: { boost: 1, type: string, index: not_analyzed }
        cik: { boost: 2, type: string, index: not_analyzed }
        conformedName: { boost: 6, analyzer: custom_analyzer }
        assignedSIC:
            type: object
            properties:
                id: { type: string, index: not_analyzed }
                code: { type: string, index: not_analyzed }
                title: { analyzer: custom_analyzer }
        businessAddress:
            type: object
            properties:
                street1: { analyzer: custom_analyzer }
                street2: { analyzer: custom_analyzer }
                city: { analyzer: custom_analyzer }
                state: { analyzer: custom_analyzer }
                zip: { type: string, index: not_analyzed }
                phone: { type: string, index: not_analyzed }
```

I want to filter by city, state and zip of the nested businessAddress property.

I have this query:

```
$boolQuery = new BoolQuery();
$cityQuery = new Match();
$cityQuery->setFieldQuery('businessAddress.city', array($city]));
$cityQuery->setFieldParam('businessAddress.city', 'analyzer', 'custom_analyzer');
$boolQuery->addMust($cityQuery);
$this->finder->find($boolQuery);
```

json query as

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"businessAddress.city":{‌​"query":["NY"],"anal‌​yzer":"custom_analyz‌​er"}}}]}}}
```

But have 0 results, i dont know if the sintax businessAddress.city will be handled automatically by the bundle or do i need to create a nested query. In case that is a nested query how i can build that?

## EDIT

After some comments below i notice i was setting match term as array, now i change from:

```
$cityQuery->setFieldQuery('businessAddress.city', array($city]));
```

to

```
$cityQuery->setFieldQuery('businessAddress.city', $city]);
```

resulting on json query:

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"businessAddress.state":{"query":"NY","analyzer":"custom_analyzer"}}}]}}}
```

i have check over internet and found nothing.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Can you export `$boolQuery` as a json. You can use `->toArray()` method.

Comment: @hkulekci here it is {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"businessAddress.city":{"query":["NY"],"analyzer":"custom_analyzer"}}}]}}}

Comment: This query did not work in elasticsearch directly. Match query does not support array value while searching. Can you check your error response of your query? Did Elastica return any error?

Comment: hi @hkulekci no elastica do not throw or log any error, it only returns 0 data

Comment: @hkulekci i update the question with some changes i perform from your comment, sadly no look

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to implement it with a nested query.

First of all you need to update your mapping to make your `businessAddress`a type `nested`

```
...
    businessAddress:
        type: nested
...
```

Then you will be able to perform the following `Nested` query

```
$boolQuery = new BoolQuery();
$cityQuery = new Match();
$cityQuery->setFieldQuery('businessAddress.city', array($city]));
$cityQuery->setFieldParam('businessAddress.city', 'analyzer', 'custom_analyzer');
$boolQuery->addMust($cityQuery);
// nested query
$query = new Nested();
$query->setPath('businessAddress');
$query->setQuery($boolQuery);
// pass the nested query to your finder
$this->finder->find($query);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that if you have only one condition in your match query the `BoolQuery` is not mandatory